# How to use ternary conditional- flutter

Tags: json, flutter

so each user has different price allocated, some has more than 1 price i want to show only if price belongs to user then it should only show that price under that user instead of showing all prices under all user and show a blank if prices doesn't belong to user.

screenshot:

[image]

//imagine that levelsData is already stored with jsonArray data

jsonArray data:

```
{
    "price":  1540,
    "user_id": "user2"
}
```

So i want to be able to display in the tile only if ***userId*** is equal to ***element[user_id]*** because previously it displayed everything, so with this code i was able to filter according to that condition but if it doesn't meet the requirement, it shows an empty space instead. i dont know how to only show information without that empty space shown

```
var levelsData = [];


class StuffInTiles extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userId;
  final int price;

  StuffInTiles(this.userId, this.price);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> _getChildren() {
      List<Widget> children = [];
      levelsData.forEach((element) {
        children.add(
          ListTile(
            dense: true,
            title: Text(
                userId == element['user_id']
                    ? "@" + element['price'].toString()
                    : ""),
          ),
        );
      });
      return children;
    }
```

Comment: A screenshot might help. To me it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: done! so sorry, hope it would be clearer

Comment: Why don't you filter the `levelsData` first to contain only data for that `userid`. Something like `levelsData.where((test) => userId == element['user_id']).forEach(.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add the empty listTile then just check the condition before adding it to the children list.

```
levelsData.forEach((element) {
  if(userId == element['user_id']) {
    children.add(
      ListTile(
        dense: true,
        title: "@" + element['price'].toString()),
    );
  }
}
```